# React setState no se actualiza con onChange

Tags: javascript, reactjs, javascript-objeto, react-hooks, async-await

Estoy aprendiendo React y tengo un problema con useState, necesito que se actualice después de escribir 5 caracteres en un input. Se que el problema tiene que ver con la asincronía de useState, sin embargo no he podido resolverlo.

```
  const [codigoInfo,setcodigoInfo]= useState({
    state:'',
    info:[]
  })

    ------------------------------------
    const cpChange = (e) => {
    e.persist();
    setRFC({...rfc, [e.target.name]: e.target.value});
    console.log(e.target.value.length)
    if(e.target.value.length === 5){
     setcodigoInfo({...codigoInfo,state:'exito'})
     console.log(codigoInfo)   
       }
     }
```

Digamos que al poner los 5 números en el input, la primera vez en el console.log el state aparece como state: " " , al borrar algun caracter y escribir otro, el state si hace el update. Quisiera hacer este set desde el inicio.

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow Español, tu pregunta es muy popular en la comunidad, por favor revisa alguna de estas publicaciones [React async 1](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/422484/react-estado-tarda-en-actualizarse/422512#422512), [React Async 2](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/374132/método-render-me-duplica-los-datos/374167#374167) puede que aclares tus dudas, si consideras que alguna fue de utilidad vota por ella, saludos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No vas a poder obtener el valor actualizado de `codigoInfo` dentro de la misma función donde lo estas seteando.

Cuando acabe de procesar la función entera de `cpChange`, es cuando el componente se va a renderizar de nuevo con los cambios que has hecho en el `codigoInfo` aplicados, dentro de la misma función no vas a tener nunca el valor actualizado.

Si pones ese mismo `console.log` fuera de la función, pero dentro del componente, verás que cada vez que el componente renderize te va a mostrar el valor de `codigoInfo`, y en el momento que llegue a los 5 carácteres se mostrará actualizado.